# GORM: ilke and inList combination

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria, dynamic-finders

In Grails, with DynamicFinder how can we execute a query using ilike along with inList? Or can we use CriteriaBuilder to combine ilike and inList? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like the CriteriaBuilder is the way to go - but could you give an example of what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want do combine ilike and inList? InList is a constraint and defined as follows http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/inList.html. So your attribte with this constraint can only hold data defined in this list. e.g.

```
name(inList:["Frey", "Fred", "Flip"] )

Test.createCriteria.list {
    like("name","F%")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build query on the fly:

```
def filter = ['a', 'bb', 'c']

def res = DomainClass.withCriteria {
  or {
    filter.each { 
      ilike('property', "%$it%")
    }
  }
}
```